# How to combine columns of date information into one date column? (each column is currently a different date)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, tableau-api

I have this COVID data set from [John Hopkins University](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdOTw.png), which I've imported into Tableau [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYXfx.png). However, it's showing each of the date columns as separate measures. Is there anyway to combine it into one column of dates instead?

I tried to unpivot the data set using SQL:

1. I used pgfutter to import the .csv file from JHU website into PostgreSQL
2. This then shows up in PostgreSQL as such [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SuiW.png)
3. I tried to unpivot the data with this code for the first 2 days.

```
select province_state, country_region, lat, long, date(generate_series('2020-01-22', '2020-01-23', '1 day'::interval)), new_cases
from time_series_covid19_confirmed_global
    cross join lateral (
        values ('2020-01-22',_1_22_20),('2020-01-23',_1_23_20)) as t(date,new_cases) 
group by date, country_region, province_state, lat, long, new_cases
order by date, country_region, province_state;
```

4. [This was the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn9Vd.png) Unsure why there are double line per record? Also, is there an easier way to do this instead of cross joining every single day?

Thank you!

Comment: Tableau can pivot your data for you easily. Read about pivoting in the Tableau help. For complex cases, you can use Tableau Prep Builder to specify your pivot.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore thank you! I belatedly learned that Tableau allowed pivoting (am currently a very new user with all these tools haha). Am now just looking for a way to do this efficiently in the data prep part of the step so that it can flow easily into Tableau :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this in your `select`:

```
date(generate_series('2020-01-22', '2020-01-23', '1 day'::interval))
```

That is causing the duplicates.  In general, you can only create new rows using `join`s in the `from` clause.  However, Postgres allows (some) table returning functions in the `select` -- and these also multiple the number of rows.  I always put such functions in the `from` clause to avoid such problems.

Instead, you just want `t.date` in the `select`.

I'm also guessing that you don't need the `group by`:

```
select province_state, country_region, lat, long, t.date, new_cases
from time_series_covid19_confirmed_global cross join lateral
     (values ('2020-01-22'::date, _1_22_20),('2020-01-23', _1_23_20)
     ) t(date, new_cases) 
order by date, country_region, province_state;
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Is there anyway in SQL to run this efficiently without having to type out every date? Someone else had suggested R but I haven't learned R yet. Would this work in Python?

Comment: @YahNahHah . . . Not really.  But I might suggest that you investigate the covid datasets in Google BigQuery.  The data is in multiple formats there.

Comment: gotcha, will check that out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Tableau itself by using Pivot. I downloaded your data and tried in my tableau. Please follow the screenshots -

- **STEP 1**
  Select all the columns you wish to pivot and right click as shown here and select "**Add data to Pivo**t"
  [image: Select all the columns you wish to pivot and right click as shown here]
- **STEP 2**
  Pivoted column can be found towards the end of the table (usually) and you can easily rename it as I did in this screenshot
  [image: Pivoted column can be found towards the end of the table (usually) and you can easily rename it as I did in this screenshot]

I hope this helps.You can format other columns in similar way.